# IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

Tried to convert a column to categorical data for NN classification. The column has 6 classes

[image]

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train = to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=5)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test,num_classes=5)
```

The error obtained is

```
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5.
```

What should I do to clear this?

Answer (score 2):

`y_train = to_categorical(y_train)`

This will do the job, as `num_classes` is default considered as `y_train + 1` by tf.to_categorical

Answer (score 0):

If the column has 6 classes then why are you passing `num_classes=5` in `to_categorical`.
Try

```
y_train = to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=6)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test,num_classes=6)
```

Comment: Tried but it throws                                                     
                                                                               
IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6. What should I do to clear this?

Comment: @MAGanesh As I can see in the image provided by you ,the value of the classes are greater than 6. Can you try and get them in range of 0-5 , for example : if your class values are [5,6,7,8,9,10] then subtract 5 from each of them so that the class values become [0,1,2,3,4,5] . I think the image that you have attached is of pandas dataframe , in pandas you can easily subtract 5 from the whole column using `df['Signal_Strength'] = df['Signal_Strength']-5`

Answer (score 0):

The values of the label are out of range - try.

```py
C_ = min(y_train.min() - y_test.min())
y_train = to_categorical(y_train - C_ ,num_classes=5)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test - C_ ,num_classes=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

*i had this error* but i **changed my number of my model class**

**you should your class start from 0 to** *...*

for example :
my class is be `1,7,8,25,36` it should be change `1->0,7->1,8->2,25->3,36->4` and the new class is be `0,1,2,3,4` it not `1,7,8,25,36`

*before using* `train_test_split`

ok